# update objects in Salesforce using WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

My question is about converting xml into json in WSO2 ESB.I'm using salesforce Rest API connector to update sobject in salesforce.
My request is as follows

```
<body>
<fandV>
 <name>Acount Name</name>
 <description>Account Description</description>
 <fandV>
</body>
```

I want to convert above response to json object as follows, in order to pass as the fieldandvalue in SalesForce update function.

```
{ "name":"Acount Name", "description":"Account Description"}
```

Salesforce Rest API update method sample is follows

```
 <salesforcerest.update>
    <sObjectName>Opportunity</sObjectName>
    <fieldAndValue>{get-property('fb')}</fieldAndValue>
    <Id>0069E000007FmBeQAK</Id>
 </salesforcerest.update>
```

Appreciate if anyone gives suggestion on this

Comment: what's `fb` here?

Comment: that's a property to store the body from the request

Answer (score 1):

If any conversion is required it always suggested to use xslt, however in your case if the conversion is small then you can go ahead with payload mediator, below is the code which should work for your payload.

```
 <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{ "name":"$1", "description":"$2"}</format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//body/fandV/name/text()"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//body/fandV/description/text()"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, But I use this for a PATCH API. so the attributes can be vary. ex: it can be name and description both or it can be only name.

Comment: You can use filter mediator in that case.

Comment: @nad.SN if the attributes and elements are varying then always convert them using xslt mediator ,By adding multiple conditions in your sequence your code will look messy and unreadable to others.

Comment: @amg_amit Yes I can use mediator.But the thing is i cant directly convert that into Json.as I know for XML there should be root element.but the json object that i want does not contain a Root object.

Comment: @nad.SN You have to frame the json payload in xslt mediator and then set content type and message type as application/json , this should work even if you do not have root element